# How to get the file excerpts for search using box api?

Tags: search, box-api

http://developers.box.com/docs/#search

This api returns only the files/folders related to the search query. How do I show the search excerpts?
Should I integrate solr/lucene for search?

EDIT:

I mean excerpt from the content of the files/documents. The search snippets that you see like in google.

Example:
http://www.bestrank.com/files/uploads/39/image/anatomy-of-a-search-engine-snippet.png
The description in this case.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by 'search excerpts?' Maybe give an example of what you'd like to see?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to your question? We're facing the same issue now. And our guess is that Box never got around to adding it, as was mentioned by @seanrose in his answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Box API currently does not provide this in the search response, but we're looking at adding it sometime in the future.